# Morning weight workouts and nutrition

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, nutrition, muscle-gain

I want to switch to morning weight workouts rather than evening ones. I am trying to lose fat and build muscle. Part of that is low carb diet high in protein. What should I eat before my morning workout and what should I eat post workout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, quit the low carb diet and switch to a [balanced one](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/healthy-diet) (also [here](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/guidelines/)). You don't really need to eat anything special before workout, just eat anything that you can easily digest. For muscle growth you could add some protein (albumin and whey protein for example). For weight loss you should avoid fat and sugar. Skipping breakfast is fine too, but it might increase the risk of gastritis. Post workout definitely whey plus a balanced meal.

There's [little scientific evidence](https://www.precisionnutrition.com/nutrient-timing) that the timing of your meals has a significant effect on muscle gain, but it probably matters for weight loss. And whey protein helps you feel full without eating a lot of calories (proteins in general are [appetite suppressants](https://www.nature.com/news/2006/060904/full/060904-3.html)). Small meals throughout the day help with your metabolism, with digestion, and prevent the dilation of your stomach (which in turn also helps with reducing your appetite).

I should note that the main challenge with weight loss is the long term. Sticking with diet and regular exercise is hard. It all has to do with the psychological effects of [caloric deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caloric_deficit). Don't try radical diets or extreme exercise routines that you know you wont be able to stick to for too long. If you do decide to do intense workouts or restrict your diet in any way (like low carb, etc.), then you should definitely consult a nutritionist or a doctor first.